# Scale or resize a sprite with image

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

The idea is: I have a sprite with rectangle image

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Rectangle.png"];
```

When I touch the sprite, 8 red points will appear

[image]

Holding a point and drag it to scale(resize) the image like this
[image]
 Can anyone show me how to do or give me a sample code.

Comment: Use sprite.scaleX and sprite.scaleY

Comment: tks for that, but how can I get that value, how do I know portion of scale

Comment: For simple rectangle shape you have to calculate stretched x and y, and i guess you know that from your last question.

Comment: Yes, I knew that but it seem doesn't right. At the first time I scale, it's ok, after that it doesn't continue from the last portion. I don't know why. How about I give you my project and you take a look for me?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but you can redraw a texture on that 8 points.

It seems similar to draw texture of soft body. I have implemented that for my game and in that i use 12 points and on that 12 point i tried to draw the texture.

So what you can do is you have to redraw the texture on that points when any of the point dragged. This is a tutorial for soft body,but You can refer this tutorial for reference.

http://www.uchidacoonga.com/2012/04/soft-body-physics-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-part-44/

It's not the same thing what you are looking for but yes using this you can implement.

Comment: tks, I'm gonna take a look